# To have a leak in your attic

Tags: idioms

I came across the following phrase yesterday. It's a somewhat old phrase which we no longer use these days.

Context:
The guy definitely **has a leak in his attic**. Make sure you go in there with a policeman.

I'd appreciate some insights into the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: It's similar in spirit to [these sorts of expressions](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a%20few%20bricks%20shy%20of%20a%20load).

Comment: Never heard the phrase meaning anything other than its literal meaning. And, for me, that's not enough context to determine otherwise. *Where* did you "come across" the phrase?

Comment: Based on that limited context, I'd guess that since the 'attic' is the top room in a house it's actually saying 'he's not "right in the head"'. He's 'got a screw loose', and his behaviour is liable to be unpredictable to the extent that it could be dangerous, hence the suggestion of police accompaniment.

Comment: Note that "a leak in the basement" is something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a common phrase and I doubt ever was but as @Gnawme and @SteveLovell point out, given the context, it's clearly one of a class of euphemisms that suggest that someone is insane.  ["Toys in the attic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toys_in_the_Attic) is a similar phrase that is more common.

Comment: The phrase ["Not right upstairs"](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/not_right_upstairs/synonyms/adjective) is the closest I've heard in conversation. Collins dictionary also carries a definition for [Leak in the Attic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/7583/Leak+in+the+attic).

Comment: @Steve it's a suggested 'word', pending investigation. I wonder if Collins has entries for all the variants, which are actually much more common.

Comment: Another similar one is having ***bats in the/one’s belfry***.

Answer (score 0):

They use this exact phrase in at least 2 eps of the Twilight Zone. In both instances they’re more or less to say “they’re not right in the head.” One ep is “A Most Unusual Camera.” I forget what the other one was.

Comment: Please don't add your opinion about the website to your answers.

Comment: The other episode, which I just now finished watching, is called "Four O'clock" The man's landlady warns a visitor that she'd better take a policeman with her because he "had a leak in his attic a mile wide."

Answer (score 0):

Similar to saying someone has a loose screw. To say someone's got a leak in their attic is an implication of them being crazy.